# Integral of $\int{\tan^{5}(x)\sec^4(x)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Here's my attempt at the problem:
$\int{\tan^{5}(x)\sec^4(x)}dx= 
\int{\frac{\sin^5(x)}{\cos^9(x)}}\,dx=
\int{\frac{\sin(x)(\sin^2(x))^2}{\cos^9(x)}}\,dx=
\int{\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x))^2}{\cos^9(x)}}\,dx=
\int{\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{u^9}}\,du=
\int{\frac{u^4-2u^2+1}{u^9}}\,du=
\int{\Big(\frac{1}{u^5}-\frac{2}{u^7}+\frac{1}{u^9}}\Big)  \,du=
-\frac{1}{4u^4}+\frac{1}{3u^6}-\frac{1}{8u^8}+C=
-\frac{\sec^4(x)}{4}+\frac{\sec^6(x)}{3}-\frac{\sec^8(x)}{8}+C$

It seems, however, that the actual answer should be: $\frac{\sec^4(x)}{4}-\frac{\sec^6(x)}{3}+\frac{\sec^8(x)}{8}+C$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $$d( \cos x ) = - \sin x dx $$

Comment: So should $\int{\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{u^9}}du$ instead be $-\int{\frac{(1-u^2)^2}{u^9}}du$ in the above solution?

Comment: yesssssssssssssssss

Comment: What confuses me then is the solution to a somewhat similar problem: https://postimg.org/image/m17rgqh2x/. Specifically, the two underlined steps don't seem to follow the same logic

Comment: Ok, Remember, this:

$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx = - \int_b^a f(x) dx $$

Comment: I'm blind! Thanks! I didn't even notice they had swapped $a$ and $b$ in that solution. Everything's clear now

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you consider using Pythagorean relation of tan and sec?

Comment: @LanierFreeman Yeah. My textbook uses the tan / sec relation to solve the problem, but I was curious to see if it could be done easily with sin / cos

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $u=\tan(x),\,du=\sec^2(x)\,dx$

\begin{eqnarray}
\int\tan^5(x)\sec^4(x)\,dx&=&\int\tan^5(x)\sec^2(x)\sec^2(x)\,dx\\
&=&\int\tan^5(x)\left[\tan^2(x)+1\right]\sec^2(x)\,dx\\
&=&\int u^5\left(u^2+1\right)\,du\\
&=&\int u^7+u^5\,du\\
&=&\frac{1}{8}u^8+\frac{1}{6}u^6+c\\
&=&\frac{1}{8}\tan^8(x)+\frac{1}{6}\tan^6(x)+c
\end{eqnarray}